# Java JMF Player not working

Tags: java, jmf

I tried to do a simple mp3 player in Java using `JMF`.

I tried with some `.mp3` and `.wav` files but it doesn't work. `BlueJ` doesn't show me any error, only that `toURL()` has been deprecated as a warning.

I read about an mp3 codec and I tried also to put it in the main function but nothing changed.

The most of the code is button management but I leave it anyway.

Full code is here:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.media.*;
import javax.media.format.AudioFormat;

public class AudioPlayerTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Player audioPlayer = null;
String audioPath = "";

public AudioPlayerTest() {
    initComponents();
    audioPath = "C:\\test.mp3";
    initAudioPlayer(audioPath);       
}

private void initAudioPlayer(String pathname) {
    try {
        URL url = new File(pathname).toURL();
        audioPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(url);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoPlayerException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CannotRealizeException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void initComponents() {

    mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    PlayButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    PauseButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    StopButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    PlayButton.setText("Play");
    PlayButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            PlayButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    PauseButton.setText("Pause");
    PauseButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            PauseButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    StopButton.setText("Stop");
    StopButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StopButtonActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout mainPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(mainPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(mainPanelLayout);
    mainPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
           .addComponent(PlayButton)
            .addGap(27, 27, 27)
            .addComponent(PauseButton)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(StopButton)
            .addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    mainPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
        mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
       .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(mainPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(PlayButton)
                .addComponent(PauseButton)
                .addComponent(StopButton))
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(mainPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}

private void PlayButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    audioPlayer.start();
}

private void PauseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    audioPlayer.stop();
}

private void StopButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    audioPlayer.stop();
    audioPlayer.setMediaTime(new Time(0.0));
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new AudioPlayerTest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private javax.swing.JButton PauseButton;
private javax.swing.JButton PlayButton;
private javax.swing.JButton StopButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
}
```

Comment: Any exceptions or console output?

Comment: @user489041 Seems not.